# Entity Framework: How do I delete a record by its primary key?

Tags: entity-framework

How do I delete a record by its primary key without first doing a SELECT statement to load the entity?

Answer (score 21):

You can use dummy object:

```
var entity = new YourEntity { Key = yourKey };
context.Entities.Attach(entity);
context.Entities.DeleteObject(entity);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: As of EF 5.0 you need to use context.Entities.Remove(entity); instead of context.Entities.DeleteObject(entity);

Comment: Also, `Attach` is no longer necessary before calling `Remove`.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of the Entity Framework are you using?

If you're using Entity Framework 4.1 or above, and using the DbContext class, you can use the ExecuteSqlCommand() method to send a DELETE statement to the database. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/04/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-10-raw-sql-queries.aspx (look at the Sending Raw Commands to the Database section). This will look something like:

```
DbContext ctx = ... get your DbContext somehow...
ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM Foo WHERE FooID = 17");
```

If you're using Entity Framework 4.0 and ObjectContext (instead of DbContext) there's a similar ExecuteStoreCommand method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when you're reading this, verify the state of [this ticket](https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1852563-simple-static-delete-and-update-methods) before implementing any hacks.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. Please vote for it if you can.